Rank function in R
Given a vector of values
x <- c(0.016, 0.036, 0.015, 0.022, 0.022, 0.043, 0.024, 0.012, 
       0.018, 0.005, 0.005, 0.036, 0.062, 0.028, 0.024)

I then use the rank function in R on this vector
rank(x, ties.method ="average") and obtain this result
[1]  5.0 12.5  4.0  7.5  7.5 14.0  9.0  3.0  6.0  1.5  1.5 12.5 15.0 11.0 10.0

It seems that its not correct for the value 0.024, which should be 9.5?

I cannot reproduce your problem since I got 5.0 12.5  4.0  7.5  7.5 14.0  9.5  3.0  6.0  1.5  1.5 12.5 15.0 11.0  9.5

Hello @ThomasIsCoding. Many thanks for your reply. I only realised the opearations now.  I started with
x <- c(0.816, 0.836, 0.815, 0.822, 0.822, 0.843, 0.824, 0.788
, 0.782, 0.795, 0.805, 0.836, 0.738, 0.772, 0.776)
then I did this
x.dash <- x- 0.8
x.dashabs <- abs(x.dash)
R.X<- rank(x.dashabs)
Now, my x.dashabs should be the x I originally posted in the question, but the R.X computed in this case end up having the result I posted in the original question.
